# Use actions inside AsyncCallback

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates, asynccallback

My class does the following (simplified):

```
public void Startup(Action myAction)
{
    _myAction = myAction;
}

private void EstablishApplicationEndpoint()
{
    ...
    ApplicationEndpoint.BeginEstablish(OnApplicationEndpointEstablishCompleted, null);
}

private void OnApplicationEndpointEstablishCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
{
    try
    {
        ...
        _myAction();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception);
    }
}
```

The `BeginEstablish` method takes an `AsyncCallback` as first parameter.

However `myAction` is never executed (I use the class from a console application). The action should output something to the console and read a line, but the console is closed immediately.

My console application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StartPlatform();
}

private static void StartPlatform()
{
    ...
    _platformController.Startup(SendContext);
}

private static void SendContext()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to send context");
    Console.ReadLine();
    ...
}
```

As the console can't know that a `ReadLine`- call will come at some time it closes automatically. How can I prevent to do so?

Comment: Why do you assume it's never executed? What does this action do? What behavior are you seeing?

Comment: The action should output something to the console and read a line, but the console is closed immediately.

Comment: How are you calling your code? Show us the `Main` method. Generally, it's advisable to create a [mcve] of your problem.

Comment: Are you calling the corresponding `EndEstablish` method at some point? If not, then your console application will exit without waiting for the callback, as the `BeginEstablish` method returns control immediately to the next statement.

Comment: I guess I know why. The console can't "predict" that a `ReadLine` call is coming (it's asynchronous) and so it's closed immediately.

Comment: @chamila-c You are right. How can I prevent to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the 'Asynchronous Programming Model (APM)' pattern:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963(v=vs.110).aspx

This model is typified by the use of `Begin` and `End` methods.

Note that when a `Begin` method (such as your `BeginEstablish`) is invoked,  the work denoted by the callback method is scheduled to occur on a separate (background) thread, and program control is returned *immediately* in the main thread.

The assumption is that other computation can occur on the main thread, at some point the callback will have completed on the background thread, and the results of the background thread will then be re-joined to the main thread.

The mechanism for re-joining is a call to a corresponding `End` method (so in your case, a call to `EndEstablish`). As such, to prevent your console application from exiting due to the immediate return of control from the call to `BeginEstablish`, you need to do the following:

- Maintain a reference to the the `IAsyncResult` object that is returned from the `Begin` call
- At some point in the code path following the call to `Begin`, call the corresponding `End`, passing in the `IAsyncResult` object obtained from the call to `Begin`
- Optionally use the second parameter to the `Begin` call to manage state

What this might look like is:

```
private IAsyncResult EstablishApplicationEndpoint()
{
    ...
    return ApplicationEndpoint.BeginEstablish(OnApplicationEndpointEstablishCompleted, null);
}
```

...

```
private static void StartPlatform()
{
    ...
    _platformController.Startup(SendContext);
    var asyncResult = _platformController.EstablishApplicationEndpoint();

    // Do other things

    // Re-join the callback
    ApplicationEndpoint.EndEstablish(asyncResult);
}
```

Keep in mind that if the callback has not yet completed by the time `End` is called, `End` will at that point block and wait for the callback to complete.

Since your callback is interacting with the Console, I suspect this will mean the call to `End` will be blocking in your case.